# Best way to simplify networkx graph where A > 1 and B > 1 is restructured as A - B?

Tags: python, pandas, graph, networkx

I have a Pandas dataframe with two columns of a different type, e.g.

```
User | Computer
1      A
2      B
3      A
```

I have created a networkx graph using the from_pandas_dataframe method and can successfully plot it visually. It shows each node and each relationship between those that were Users and those that were Computers as an edge.

What I'm really interested in though, is the relationship between the Users. I.e. in the example, User 1 is linked to User 3 because they both have Computer A in common. I'd like a way to refactor my graph to only show Users as nodes and to have the Computers as the edges which connect the two users (note that I don't have to retain the data of which computer forms the edge although that would be nice).

I've tried some self-joins but the output hasn't really worked how I wanted:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user':['a','b','c','d', 'd', 'e'], 'computer':[1,1,2,3,1,1]})
df



id user computer
0   a   1
1   b   1
2   c   2
3   d   3
4   d   1
5   e   1

joined = df.join(df, on='computer', rsuffix='y')
joined

id  user    computer    usery   computery
0   a   1   b   1
1   b   1   b   1
2   c   2   c   2
3   d   3   d   3
4   d   1   b   1
5   e   1   b   1
```

In the above example, I'm not getting the pair AD even though both are associated with Computer 1.

What's the best way to achieve this? Should it be through manipulating the data in Pandas to somehow show those pairings between users only? If so how? Or should I be doing it through networkx?

Comment: How large is this graph? Very large operations should take place in pandas if you can, since it'll be substantially faster (even, in many cases, to run a more complex algorithm). But for a few thousand rows, a networkx algorithm will probably be easier to write and maintain.

Comment: I think what you're looking at is a bipartite projection. https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.bipartite.projection.overlap_weighted_projected_graph.html

Comment: It won't be large, mostly likely less than 1k nodes

Comment: That looks pretty complicated but I'll take a look. I've also played with doing self-joins but that hasn't quite worked out yet either. I'm happy to lose the edge data if I can easily create a dataframe of just User to User pairs that reflect the above.

Comment: I don't think the bipartite is what I want. Thats more suitable if I wanted to keep both my Users and Computers as nodes. I want to get rid of the Computers as nodes and just have Users.

Comment: You are exactly describing the bipartite_projection commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to convert your graph into a set of fully connected subgraphs whose nodes are the users.

repeating your code:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame(
{'user':['a','b','c','d', 'd', 'e'], 'computer':[1,1,2,3,1,1]})
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='user', target='computer')

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
colours = [('red' if str(node).isdigit() else 'blue') for node in G.nodes]
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, label=True, node_color=colours)
```

[image]

So, if you want to make new individual graphs that have only the blue nodes, you can use [nx.connected_component_subgraphs:](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_component_subgraphs.html)

```
import itertools

subgraphs = []

for cc in nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G):
    # collect all nodes in the connected subgraph that aren't labeled with digits
    nodes = [a for a in cc.nodes if not str(a).isdigit()]
    Subgraph = nx.Graph()
    Subgraph.add_nodes_from(nodes)
    # generate all pairwise combinations for these nodes and add as edges:
    Subgraph.add_edges_from(itertools.combinations(nodes, 2))

    subgraphs.append(Subgraph)

# optional:    
# combine all subgraphs into a new graph
G_new = nx.compose(*subgraphs)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G_new)
nx.draw_networkx(G_new, pos)
```

[image]

drawing weighted edges takes some reworking:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='user', target='computer')

# add some more connections
G.add_nodes_from([4,5,6])
G.add_edges_from([(4, 'b'), (4, 'a'), (5, 'b'), (5, 'c'), (6, 'b'), (6, 'a')])

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
colours = [('red' if str(node).isdigit() else 'blue') for node in G.nodes]
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, label=True, node_color=colours)
```

[image]

```
import itertools

# collect all connection nodes
connecting_nodes = [n for n in G.nodes if str(n).isdigit()]

edgelist = []

for cn in connecting_nodes:

    # create all combinations of adjacent nodes and store in list of tuples
    edgelist += itertools.combinations(G.neighbors(cn), 2)

#remove positional information
edgelist = [tuple(sorted(list(set(a)))) for a in edgelist]

from collections import Counter

# now count occurences of each tuple (= number of "independent connections"
# between two non-digit nodes).
# Counter(edgelist) returns a dict, i.e. {('a', 'b'): 2, ...},
# which can be unpacked like so:
weighted_edges = [(*u, v) for u,v in Counter(edgelist).items()]

# now make new graph with non-digit nodes and add weighted edges:
H = nx.Graph()
H.add_nodes_from([n for n in G.nodes if not str(n).isdigit()])
H.add_weighted_edges_from(weighted_edges)

# and draw, with width proportional to weight
pos = nx.spring_layout(H)
weights = [e[2]['weight'] for e in H.edges(data=True)]

nx.draw_networkx(H, pos, width=weights)
```

[image]

Comment: That's very slick. To further complicate things, how could I use the value of the 'red connecting nodes' as the value associated with the edges now connecting the blue nodes? e.g. Is there a way so that if two 'users' were connected by a high number of 'computers', I could thicken the connecting line?

Comment: Thats really cool. Any recommendations of where to learn more about this type of stuff?

Comment: I just like puzzling things out, so I don't have formal knowledge about this type of analysis. For formal knowledge I would try to find a course or a textbook on network analysis, or graph theory.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think using an inner join on the DB is indeed cleaner than using a graph operation. In pandas, the join can be executed as such:

```
import pandas as pd 

def get_edges(df, var, on):
    """Get all combinations of variable var that share a value for variable on (using an inner join)."""
    inner_self_join = df.merge(df, how='inner', on=on)
    excluding_self_pairs = inner_self_join[inner_self_join[var + '_x']!=inner_self_join[var + '_y']]
    edges = excluding_self_pairs[[var + '_x', var + '_y']].values
    return edges

df = pd.DataFrame({'user':['a','b','c','d', 'd', 'e'], 'computer':[1,1,2,3,1,1]})
edges = get_edges(df, 'user', 'computer')

#    array([['a', 'b'],
#       ['a', 'd'],
#       ['a', 'e'],
#       ['b', 'a'],
#       ['b', 'd'],
#       ['b', 'e'],
#       ['d', 'a'],
#       ['d', 'b'],
#       ['d', 'e'],
#       ['e', 'a'],
#       ['e', 'b'],
#       ['e', 'd']], dtype=object)
```

You can then use the edge list to create a networkx `Graph` instance.

Comment: Thanks for that, that's also a great solution. I'm going to stick with the graph option as I may need to build in some more detail from those 'edge' objects as a 'nice to have' as time goes on.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is built in to networkx using the bipartite projections.  Here is the weighted version:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame({'user':['a','b','c','d', 'd', 'e'], 'computer':[1,1,2,3,1,1]})
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='user', target='computer')

cnodes = [1,2,3] #the computers
unodes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] #the users

#create the network based only on users.  An edge means they share a computer
Uprojection = nx.algorithms.bipartite.overlap_weighted_projected_graph(G, unodes)

#the edges are weighted based on how much they share (see documentation for details)

Uprojection.edges(data=True)
>EdgeDataView([('a', 'd', {'weight': 0.5}), ('a', 'b', {'weight': 1.0}), ('a', 'e', {'weight': 1.0}), ('b', 'd', {'weight': 0.5}), ('b', 'e', {'weight': 1.0}), ('d', 'e', {'weight': 0.5})])

nx.draw(Uprojection, with_labels=True)
```

[image]

Comment: I think that this should be the accepted answer, if there is a way to change the weight of edges to `d`-nodes to 1.